# 403 apache error with alias to ntfs partition

Tags: permissions, apache2, ntfs, apache2.4

My machine is currently a dual boot between Ubuntu saucy and Win 8.1. I would like to have a common directory for my web development files and so I'm trying to make an alias for apache pointing to my shared folder on my secondary data disk.
I created a `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/linuxshare.conf` file containing:

```
Alias /lnxsh "/media/Data/LinuxShare/lampTest"
<Directory "/media/Data/LinuxShare/lampTest">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

By all I get when accessing `http://localhost/lnxsh` is:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /lnxsh/index.html on this server.

Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

I looked around the internet and found that most of the time this error was because of permission issues. After many tries I edited my fstab to mount the partitions with rwx partition with my user and group:

```
#Auto mount NTFS Data partition on /dev/sdb2
/dev/sdb2 /media/Data ntfs-3g defaults,auto,umask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000,nls=utf8 0 0
#Auto mount NTFS C: partition on /dev/sdb2
/dev/sda2 /media/Computer ntfs-3g defaults,auto,umask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000,nls=utf8 0 0
```

And with an ls -l I can easily check that I have the right permissions:

```
user@computer:/media/Data/LinuxShare/lampTest$ ll
total 1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 12 déc.   7 19:15 index.html*
```

What can I possibly be doing wrong? I've tried everything including changing apache env variables to change the user from www-data to my own user...

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have made it to owned by your usergroup, but rather - your user and the group of the webserver. If i am not mistaken it is www-data.